# See what exactly every IP is on my LAN [Windows] [PfSense]

Tags: networking, ip, pfsense

I'm using pfTop in PfSense to view all my traffic, and need a way to see what every local IP is. When I see packets getting sent to an External IP (google for example) all I have to do is search a whois report on said IP. For my local IP's I don't know exactly what each one is.

For example:

```
pfTop: Up State 1-100/303, View: default, Order: age
PR        DIR SRC                           DEST                                   STATE                AGE       EXP     PKTS    BYTES
 In  10.0.0.24:63325               104.16.60.37:443              ESTABLISHED:ESTABLISHED  13:41:42  13:41:38    11469  3278113
```

104.16.60.37 is discord. For 10.0.0.24, what exactly IS that IP? I know that it's PfSense, but .24 for example, what exactly is .24? How can I see what each of the local IP's are.

Answer (score 1):

You either look at your local devices until you find one that is that address, or you (somewhat preferably) **set** your local devices (though DHCP reservation or by manually setting them) to know what each one is.

There's no magic to it. On a household scale it should not really take that long to run them all down.

If you are serving them via DHCP you can look up the first half of the MAC address (by looking at the *DHCP Leases* under *status*) to see who made it, but often the network device is not the same brand as the device it's in. Sometimes the DHCP service will pick up a useful hostname (*e.g.* Gunner's iPhone) from the device, often it does not.